# Show that $C\in\mathbb{P}^2(k)$ is a rational curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$. 
>   We consider the curve 
>   $$C = V(X^pZ^{p-1}-Y^{2p-1})\subset\mathbb{P}^2(k)$$
>   Show that $C$ is a rational cuve.

We did this problem in class as follows:
$C$ is rational if there exists a rational parametrization. We want $\varphi_i(s,t)$ such that $\{(\varphi_0(s,t),\varphi_1(s,t),\varphi_2(s,t))|(s:t)\in\mathbb{P}^1_{k}\}=V(f)$.

Choose $\varphi_0(s,t)=s^{2p-1}, \varphi_1(s,t)=s^pt^{p-1}, \varphi_2(s,t)=t^{2p-1}$.
$\Rightarrow f(\varphi_0,\varphi_1\varphi_2)=(s^{2p-1})^p*(t^{2p-1})^{p-1}-(s^pt^{p-1})^{2p-1}=s^{2p^2-p}t^{2(p-1)^2}-s^{2p^2-p}t^{2(p-1)^2}=0.$

 
My question is, how did we find this parametrization? Only by 'looking closely' or is there any method or trick to find it quickly?

Thanks and best, Luca

Comment: Dear Luca,  will you pardon my curiosity if I ask you what class  you are attending and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rationality can be tested on any non-empty open subset let's just study the affine part $C_0\subset \mathbb A^2_k=\{Z\neq0\}$ of your curve $C$.
The equation of $C_0$ is then $x^p=y^{2p-1}$.
But in general the equation $x^a=y^b$  cries out to be parametrized by $x=s^b, y=s^a$ so that in your case the parametrization is $x=s^{2p-1}, y=s^{p}$.
If you add the homogeneizing parameter $t$ in order to have a morphism defined on the whole projective line $\mathbb P^1_k$(and not only on $\mathbb A^1_k$) you obtain your parametrization.

And you know what? The assumptions that the characteristic is $p$ and that $p$ is a prime number **are completely irrelevant!**

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's an introductory lecture in Algebraic Geometry... I know, I should know how parametrization works from school..

Comment: Dear Luca: no, no the problem was not trivial at all since it was somewhat obscured by all those $p$'s supposed to refer to the characteristic of the base field. I am quite surprised that you have been taught such mathematics  in school...

Comment: Haha, well not all the algebra behind it, but finding the parametrization, I think we learned something about it.
But thank you very much for the answer! It helped a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome, dear Luca: glad this helped you.